# How to have ArrayList of object in Model

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter . How can we have ArrayList of object in model class flutter .

Following below is the model class I have . but I need to have a list of objects in the model.

```
class MonitorModel {
  MonitorModel(this.id, this.unitName, this.customerName, this.location,
      this.dateTime, this.totalRunHour, this.lastDayRunHour);
  var id = "";
  var unitName = "";
  var customerName = "";
  var location = "";
  var anotherList<ModelList> = ArrayList()
  var dateTime = "";
  var totalRunHour = "";
  var lastDayRunHour = "";
}
```

Comment: That is the way i do it: `List<ModelList> anotherList = List<ModelList>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
class MonitorModel {
  MonitorModel(this.id, this.unitName, this.customerName, this.location, this.anotherModelList, this.dateTime, this.totalRunHour, this.lastDayRunHour);
  var id = "";
  var unitName = "";
  var customerName = "";
  var location = "";
  List<AnotherModel> anotherModelList = []; // HERE
  var dateTime = "";
  var totalRunHour = "";
  var lastDayRunHour = "";
}
```

The other model

```
class AnotherModel {
  // ...
}
```